# Finding functions that return a specific type

Tags: go

Perhaps this is a silly question, but is there a way to find all functions (in the standard library or GOPATH) that return a specific type?

For example there are many functions that take io.Writer as an argument. Now I want to know how to create an io.Writer and there are many ways to do so. But how can I find all the ways easily without guessing at packages and looking through all the methods to find those that return an io.Writer (or whatever other type I'm after)?

**Edit:** I should extend my question to also find types that implement a specific interface. Sticking with the io.Writer example (which admittedly was a bad example for the original question) it would be good to have a way to find any types that implement the Writer interface, since those types would be valid  arguments for a function that takes takes an io.Writer and thus answer the original question when the type is an interface.

Comment: `go install` [`golang.org/x/tools/cmd/oracle`](http://golang.org/s/oracle-user-manual).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my days coding I'm personally rare in need to find functions returning `Int16` and `error`(func can return few values in Go, you know)

For second part of your question there exists wonderful cmd `implements` written by Dominik Honnef `go get honnef.co/go/implements`
After discover type that satisfy your conditions you can assume constructor for type (something like `func NewTheType() TheType`) would be just after TheType declaration in source code and docs. It's a proven Go practice.

Comment: yes, agreed. I didn't get the question right the first time. The edit is basically what I meant to begin with. Just tried the implements cmd and it's perfect for this! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not the best way but take a look at the search field at the top of the official [golang.org](http://golang.org) website. If you search for `"Writer"`:

[**http://golang.org/search?q=Writer**](http://golang.org/search?q=Writer)

You get many results, grouped by categories like

- [Types](http://golang.org/search?q=Writer#Types)
- [Package-level declarations](http://golang.org/search?q=Writer#Global)
- [Local declarations and uses](http://golang.org/search?q=Writer#Local)
- [and Textual occurrences](http://golang.org/search?q=Writer#Textual)

Also note that [`io.Writer`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) is an interface, and we all know how Go handles interfaces: when implementing an interface, there is no declaration of intent, a type implicitly implements an interface if the methods defined by the interface are declared. This means that you won't be able to find many examples where an `io.Writer` is created and returned because a type might be named entirely different and still be an `io.Writer`.

Things get a little easier if you look for a non-interface type for example [`bytes.Buffer`](http://golang.org/search?q=bytes.Buffer).

Also in the documentation of the declaring package of the type the `Index` section groups functions and methods of the package *by type* so you will find functions and methods of the *same* package that return the type you're looking for right under its entry/link in the `Index` section.

Also note that you can check the dependencies of packages at [**godoc.org**](http://godoc.org). For example you can see what packages import the `io` package which may be a good starting point to look for further examples (this would be exhausting in case of package `io` because it is so general that at the moment [23410 packages import it](http://godoc.org/io?importers)).