# Documentation On "All Known Implementation" of Interfaces

Tags: go

Few months into learning Go, I just discover that [`os.File`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File) implements the [`io.Reader`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) interface by implementing the [`Read(b []byte) (n int, err error)`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Read) function. This allows me to use a buffered reader to read a file by do something like:

```
f, err := os.Open("myfile.txt")
bufReader := bufio.NewReader(f)
```

Unless I miss it, it looks like there isn't an "All Known Implementing Classes" in Go documents on interfaces, like those found in Java interfaces documentation.

Are there any ways to identify the types that implement an interface in Go?

Comment: Related: [Finding functions that return a specific type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29554369/finding-functions-that-return-a-specific-type).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can find the info you want and more using the godoc command's static analysis tools. Run the following at the command line: `godoc -http=":8080" -analysis="type"`. Using the documentation you can find out what types implement an interface and the method set for a type.

There is also a pointer analysis that allows you to find callers and callees of various types. The channel send<--->receive analysis is pretty neat.

You can also read more about the static analysis done by the godoc tool at http://golang.org/lib/godoc/analysis/help.html

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/dominikh/implements can do this:

> implements is a command line tool that will tell you which types implement which interfaces, or which interfaces are implemented by which types.

e.g.

```
~ implements -types=crypto/cipher
crypto/cipher.StreamReader implements...
        io.Reader
*crypto/cipher.StreamReader implements...
        io.Reader
crypto/cipher.StreamWriter implements...
        io.Closer
        io.WriteCloser
        io.Writer
*crypto/cipher.StreamWriter implements...
        io.Closer
        io.WriteCloser
        io.Writer
```

Answer (score 3):

For all you vim junkies out there, [vim-go](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go) supports advance code analysis using the `:GoImplements`, `:GoCallees`, `:GoChannelPeers`, `:GoReferrers` etc. oracle commands.

For example, if I have a `Calculator` interface and implementation that looks like:

```
type Arithmetic interface{
  add(float64, float64) float64 
}

type Calculator struct{}

func (c *calculator) add(o1, o2 float64) float64 {
  // ... stuff
}
```

Then running `:GoImplements` in vim with my cursor on the `type Arithmetic interface` will yield something like:

```
calculator.go|8 col 6| interface type Arithmetic
calculator.go|3 col 6| is implemented by pointer type *calculator
```

Now if I moved my cursor to the `type Calculator struct{}` line and run `:GoImplements`, I will get something like:

```
calculator.go|3 col 6| pointer type *calculator
calculator.go|8 col 6| implements Arithmetic
```

Note: If you got an "unknown command" error, try execute `:GoInstallBinaries` first before re-trying.