# Finding types in the standard library

Tags: go

Using this function (constructor):

```
func NewDecoder(r io.Reader) *json.Decoder
```

How can you identify who is a `io.Reader` in the standard library?
I know that a `os.Stdin` is one, but how do you find other readers in the standard lib?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding functions that return a specific type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29554369/finding-functions-that-return-a-specific-type)

Comment: Do you mean programmatically generate a list of functions that return an io.Reader? Or do you want to know how to discern if a type implements the io.Reader?

Comment: You read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Short of searching the GoDocs for io.Reader (https://golang.org/search?q=io.Reader) or using Google to do something similar you'd have to write a program to parse the Go Standard Library.

Perhaps a more useful avenue of inquiry would be, telling us what you're trying to accomplish.