# How to find types which implement an interface in go

Tags: go, interface

I need an io.Writer for a function. I don't know how to get one from a file...

I know interface are implicit so it complicated the search...

Comment: What do you mean by "how to get one from a file"? Are you trying to find such types programmatically? Something else?

Comment: Interfaces _aren't_ explicit, you can use anything that satisfies them. Search for the methods in question.

Comment: I want an io.writer for my function so it can use it to create a file but don't know how to get an io.Writer

Comment: a file (`*os.File`) _is_ an `io.Writer`.

Comment: How can I see easily that os.File is an io.Writer? How can I found type witch implement the interface for the next time?

Comment: `*os.File` has a [`Write`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Write) method that matches the signature of `io.Writer`. You only need to look at the method set to see what it implements. Listing all possible `io.Writers` isn't really useful, since it's such a commonly used interface.

Comment: Related: [Finding functions that return a specific type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29554369/finding-functions-that-return-a-specific-type/29554594#29554594).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the [os.File](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File) documentation: it has a [`func (*File) Write`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Write) method, which means it is a Writer.

You can use the command `guru` to list all types implementing an interface.
Notably, the **`implements` query**:

> The implements query shows interfaces that are implemented by the selected type and, if the selected type is itself an interface, the set of concrete types that implement it.
>
> An implements query on a value reports the same information about the expression’s type.
>
> An implements query on a method shows the set of abstract or concrete methods that are related to it